# Camel AWS SNS Exceptions

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-camel, amazon-sns

I am trying to send an SNS using Apache camel by using the camel sns library.

I used the documentation found here http://camel.apache.org/aws-sns.html

Where it says I need to define a client and then bind it to the registry. Therefore I have done this using this code:

```
BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
AmazonS3 client = AmazonS3Client.builder().withRegion("eu-west-1")
                        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
                        .build();

CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
            JndiRegistry registry = (JndiRegistry) ((PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry)context.getRegistry()).getRegistry();
            registry.bind("client", client);
```

Following this, inside my camel route, I am carrying out this operation

```
from(mySftp.getUri("/camel"))
to("aws-sns://"+topicArn+"?amazonSNSClient=#client")
```

With this code, I get this error -

> Failed to create route route1 at: >>>
>   To[aws-sns://arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:xxxxxx?amazonSNSClient=#client]
>   <<< in route:
>   Route(route1)[[From[sftp://xxxxxxxx...
>   because of Failed to resolve endpoint:
>   aws-sns://arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxx?amazonSNSClient=%23client
>   due to: Could not find a suitable setter for property: amazonSNSClient
>   as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor
>   type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from
>   type: java.lang.String to the required type:
>   com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNS with value #client

Apart from this, I have also tried to send an sns using the following camel route

```
.to("aws-sns://"+topicArn+"?accessKey="+accessKey+"&secretKey="+secretKey+"&amazonSNSEndpoint="+snsEndpoint)
```

but then it tells me no region is provided although my snsEnpoint is set to - `sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`

Anyone has an idea why I cannot send an sns using camel in anyway way which i try?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess there's a cut&paste typo in the example you provided for the route builder. Could you please fix it to be sure we see your exact code?
i.e. in ```from(mySftp.getUri("/camel"))
.to("aws-sns://"+topicArn+"?.to("aws-sns://"+topicArn+"?amazonSNSClient=#client")``` I see 2 `.to` invocations, but the 1st one has no right bracket

Comment: thanks, its fixed @DavideCavestro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding an `AmazonS3Client`, but it needs an `AmazonSNSClient`.

Camel cannot convert the reference to a  an `AmazonS3Client` to an instance of `AmazonSNSClient`.

See http://camel.apache.org/aws-sns.html#AWS-SNS-AdvancedAmazonSNSconfiguration

Comment: nice, didn't notice it was of S3 type. Thanks.

Comment: That being said, changing the code to 

`BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
   ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
   AmazonSNS client = new AmazonSNSClient(creds, clientConfiguration);`

doesnt have any effect. I get the same error 

" No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNS with value client"

Comment: Are you sure the bean is bound to the registry before the _routeBuilder_ is executed? Where did you put the `registry.bind...` stuff?

Comment: Hi Davide, 

This seemed to work fine for me. 

`BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
   AmazonSNS client = AmazonSNSClient.builder().withRegion("eu-west-1")
                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
                    .build();`

Thanks for your help